# Pandas - Combine Rows with Similar Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I'd like to combine certain rows. My current `df` looks something like this:

```
col1  | col2  | col3   | col4    | col5
022   | 5000  | name1  | comedy  | tag1
022   | 4250  | name1  | comedy  | tag2
512   | 6570  | name2  | drama   | tag44
730   | 7640  | name3  | drama   | tag 52
730   | 4557  | name3  | drama   | tag 53
```

If both col1 and col3 match, I want to combine the rows to create something like this:

```
col1  | col2          | col3   | col4    | col5
022   | (5000, 4250)  | name1  | comedy  | (tag1, tag2)
512   | 6570          | name2  | drama   | tag44
730   | (7640, 4557)  | name3  | drama   | (tag 52, tag 53)
```

`df.groupby(["col1", "col3"]).groups` seems to tell me which rows have overlapping data, but I'm confused as to how I can combine that data and display it like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may do something like:

```
>>> fn = lambda ts: set(ts) if len( ts.unique( ) ) > 1 else ts.iloc[0]
>>> df.groupby( ['col1','col3'], as_index=False ).aggregate( fn )

   col1   col3               col2    col4                 col5
0    22  name1  set([5000, 4250])  comedy    set([tag2, tag1])
1   512  name2               6570   drama                tag44
2   730  name3  set([7640, 4557])   drama  set([tag52, tag53])

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```